# Access non associated tables in cakephp3 controller

Tags: mysql, associations, cakephp-3.x

I am a newbie to cakephp3, I am trying to access a "table A" which is not linked to "table B" in the controller of table 2

I want to user category table in UsersController. How to achieve that?

e.g.

```
user table has three fields id, name, role
category table has 2 fields id, name
articles table has 3 fields id, user_id, category_id, article
```

Comment: Not quite a direct duplicate of [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50552444/display-name-instead-of-id-in-view-ctp-in-non-associated-tables-in-cakephp3-x), but the same underlying problem, and solution.

Comment: I am talking about non associated tables

Comment: What, specifically, do you want to use the categories table for in the users controller?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can use [loadModel()](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#loading-additional-models) to load another table that is not linked to your controller's default model.

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public function initialize() {
        parent::initialize();
        // You don't have to put it in initiliaze 
        // but if you want to use it in more than one method it's a good place
        $this->loadModel('Categories');
        $this->loadModel('Articles');
    }

    public function index() {
        // Categories is now available as $this->Categories thanks to loadModel()
        $categories = $this->Categories->find()->select(['id', 'name']);
    }

}
```